# Why free function does not work in my code?

Tags: c

I am trying to free the first row of the "b" array, but the compiler throws an error "free(): invalid pointer. Aborted"

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void    ft_edit(char ***tab)
{
    **tab = "hel";
}

int    main(void)
{
    char **b;

    b = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
    *b = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    *(b + 1) = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
    *b = "tab";
    *(b + 1) = "tac";
    printf("Before: %s\n", *b);
    ft_edit(&b);
    free(b[0]);
    printf("After: %s\n", *b);
    printf("%s", *(b + 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You switch back and forth between array notation and differencing pointers. Settle on one for the same variable, there's no reason whatsoever in this case to use both.

Comment: You overwrite the value in `b[0]` with `*b = "tab";`, so `free(b[0]);` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Or, to put it a little differently: `*b = "tab"` isn't storing data in the memory you malloc'd, it's making the pointer point to a constant string, and overwriting / throwing away the pointer that `malloc()` returned you. (Anyhow, `"tab"` requires 4 chars to store, not 3, because of the NUL terminator; so even if you properly copied content into it with `strncpy()` or similar, `3*sizeof(char)` isn't enough space).

Comment: *Moreover*, even if `free()` worked properly, there are no guarantees about what your "After:" lines would print, because trying to access free'd memory is undefined behavior. An implementation would be completely within its rights to crash, or to give no outward appearance of having released the memory back to the pool to be used by future `malloc()`s done by the same process.

Comment: Note that being called a [Three-Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer) is not really a compliment.  As a learning exercise, using a triple pointer (three stars) may conceivably have some value.  In production code, it is most often a red flag.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, I am not looking for being called anything, its just an exercise to understand how pointers to pointers work.

Comment: In general, any time you are faced with the problem "Some C-library function isn't working correctly...", there is a near 100% chance it isn't the C-library function at fault. There is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: Note that `*(b + 1)` has a shortcut syntax `b[1]` that should be used instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the things you have to keep straight when working with strings and pointers is when you can assign pointers, versus when you want to explicitly copy content between different pointers.  In particular, when you say

```
*b = (char *)malloc(3 * sizeof(char));
```

followed by

```
*b = "tab";
```

you are, to put it bluntly, doing it wrong.  You're overwriting the dynamically-allocated pointer `malloc` gave you (losing it in the process), and replacing it with a valid, but non-dynamically-allocated pointer to the compiler-allocated string "tab".  When you later call `free(b[0])` (which is equivalent to `free(*b)`), the pointer you're handing to `free` is the non-dynamically-allocated one, not the one you got from `malloc` -- which, as I said, you lost.  That's why you get that complaint.  (It's actually coming from the C run-time library, not from the compiler.)

To do what you're trying to do, you're going to have to copy strings, not simply assign pointers.  You're also going to have to make sure the regions you allocate are big enough.  (Remember that the size of the string "tab" is *four*, including one for the terminating `\0` character.)

Here's a corrected version.

```
void ft_edit(char ***tab)
{
    strcpy(**tab, "hel");
}

int main()
{
    char **b;

    b = malloc(sizeof(char *) * 3);
    b[0] = malloc(10);
    b[1] = malloc(10);
    b[2] = malloc(10);
    strcpy(b[0], "tab");
    strcpy(b[1], "tac");
    printf("Before: %s\n", b[0]);
    ft_edit(&b);
    printf("After: %s\n", b[0]);
    printf("%s\n", b[1]);

    free(b[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

I moved the call to `free` to the end, since you don't want to free `b[0]` before you print it.  (With that said, it's not really necessary to free `b[0]`, although if you *do* want to free things before exit, you'll also want to free `b[1]`, `b[2]`, and finally `b`.)

I also got rid of some unnecessary casts on `malloc`'s returns, and some unnecessary multiplications by `sizeof(char) in the sizes passed to it.

Comment: Nit, maybe *"compiler-allocated string"* -> *"string-literal*" and a short note that on almost all systems string-literals reside in read-only memory and that when you make the assignment `*b = "tab";` you are assigning the address of the string-literal to the pointer `b`. (all of which is somewhat a prelude to your correct explanation of where he overwrites the original pointer address)